# How to organise sell and buy orders?

Tags: eve-online

I start to try make some money by using buy and sell orders. The number of orders grows and I am little lost in my orders in game. Are there some "best practises" or useful tools to handle them?

I would like to have some filters like:
1) To see only orders in station I am in.
2) To see only orders I can modify.
3) To see only order with minimum (maximum) selling (buying) value.
4) I want to see orders that are in item category (categories).

I would like to have some better summary of ISK flow than Wallet -> Transaction is. 
1) To see ISK flow only in one station (etc.). 
2) To see ISK flow in item category (not just one item).
3) To see some statistics. (peak of selling/buying).

I am not sure how many ISK i have really in items. I am not sure what is proce of resources needed to manufacture items. (I know this one is may be too much to want but I hope in some tool.)

And some other things.
I find some usefull tools like http://eve-central.com/ but I hope in something litle more sophisticated and allowing manage of my orders.

(I am playing on lap top so I have a little problems to view all necessary statistics on monitor.)

Comment: Can you expand the question? In what way are you lost?

Comment: Like Phill.Zitt, i fail to see how we can help you if you don't give us enough information for us to figure out what's wrong with you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to say that this isn't possible, but then I remembered about [EVE MEEP](https://sites.google.com/site/evemeep/home).

You can sort transactions by item, region, system, station, character/corporation, and date via the Transactions tab, and you can even save the Filter for later use. It also has a reprocessing tab. It has a bunch of other functions as well, but those are the ones you were specific about.

It is a tad outdated, to me, and it runs a tad slow, but it hasn't crashed or failed in the five or ten minutes I've been beating on it, so it should be fairly stable.

Answer (score 2):

Eve Mentat is an app used for trading in EVE. It takes some setting up and some getting used to but helps update orders a LOT more quickly than doing it manually. I still use EVE Meep to manage research and manufacturing but I find Mentat more straightforward and useful for trading.

[EVE Mentat Link](http://www.evementat.com/)